# Regexp: substring not followed by character

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Assume a regex that should test true for any string containing the substring `hello`, followed by any string that does not begin with `!` or several of `!`.

Some examples for clarity:

```
var regExp = /someExpression/;

regExp.test("hello"); // → true
regExp.test("hello!"); // → false
regExp.test("hello!!"); // → false
regExp.test("hello!sdkfjhsdfjkh"); // → false
regExp.test("hellos!dkfjhsdfjkh"); // → true
regExp.test("hello-!"); // → true
regExp.test("hello w34~342`!!"); // → true
```

I have tried several approaches, here's my best:

```
var regExp = /.*hello[^!].*/;
```

This will work well on all cases I can come up with but one: `"hello"`.

In this case, `[^!]` expects a character.

How can I improve this regex so it tests true for this case as well?

Any kind of help is appreciated.

---

Edit - bonus points:

The same for `hello` preceded by a `!`, so that `hello` is accepted, but `!hello` is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a negative look-ahead rather than a  negated character class (that still matches, consumes characters):

```
var regExp = /.*hello(?!!).*/;
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uV3uZ9/2)

See more details at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead):

> *Negative lookahead* is indispensable if you want **to match something not followed by something else**. When explaining character classes, this tutorial explained why you cannot use a negated character class to match a `q` not followed by a `u`. Negative lookahead provides the solution: `q(?!u)`. The negative lookahead construct is the pair of parentheses, with the opening parenthesis followed by a question mark and an exclamation point.

**EDIT:**

Since JS regex engine does not support look-behind, you need to match `(^|[^!])hello` (where `(^|[^!])` matches either start of string or a symbol other than `!`) and then do whatever you need to do with it using JS string methods.

Comment: Are `.*` useful and why? Note that the method used is `test`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's perfect. I know this is not generally accepted, but would you be able to recommend a solution for another case? I'm trying to work out the same principle for hello *preceded* by `!`. Is there something such as a lookback? (this was added to the question as well in an edit)

Comment: For JS, it would be a different story as JS does not support look-behind. You need to match `(^|[^!])hello` and then manipulate the match with JS string and other methods.

Comment: Thank you! That's great help.

Answer (score 1):

With just those cases, negating `/hello!/` works just fine:

```
var regExp = /hello!/;

!regExp.test("hello"); // → true
!regExp.test("hello!"); // → false
!regExp.test("hello!!"); // → false
!regExp.test("hello-!"); // → true
!regExp.test("hello w34~342`!!"); // → true
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/xI1mG0/1

Comment: Good approach! <°)))))))))))>

Comment: While correct, this is strictly not what was asked for. Thank you though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple alternation with the end of the string:

```
/hello([^!]|$)/.test(str);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `/"hello([^!]|$)"/.test("hello");` tests false, that's no good.

Comment: @NitaiJ.Perez: sorry I made a mistake (corrected now).

Comment: Sorry, but it's been explained that a negated character is no good here. This is what I Tried as well. `/hello([^!]|$)/.test("hello!a");` tests `false` and should not.

Comment: @NitaiJ.Perez: If I understand well your question `"hello!a"` or `"hello!"` *should* return **false**, isn't it? (since a `!` follows)

Comment: Correct, it was a typo. :)
I meant for `helloa!` which tests okay. Thanks!